# Move all files in subfolders to another folder

Tags: c#, directory

My source path is `C:\Music\` in which I have hundreds of folders called Album-1, Album-2 etc.

What I want to do is create a folder called `Consolidated` in my source path.

And then I want to move all the files inside my albums to the folder `Consolidated`, so that I get all the music files in one folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check out the MSDN page at ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try like this

```
String directoryName = "C:\\Consolidated";
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

List<String> MyMusicFiles = Directory
                   .GetFiles("C:\\Music", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

foreach (string file in MyMusicFiles)
{
    FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
    // to remove name collisions
    if (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false) 
    {
         mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
    }
}
```

It will get all the files in the "C:\Music" folder (including files in the subfolder) and move them to the destination folder. The `SearchOption.AllDirectories` will recursively search all the subfolders.

Comment: what is file collusion?

Comment: @gonzobrains and anyone else – I'm pretty sure the comment should be `to remove name *collisions*`.

Comment: Files illegally conspiring with directories to make our lives difficult - that's file collusion ;-)

Comment: Important to say that this does not preserve subfolder structure. That can be adjusted by replacing mFile.Name by mFile.FullName.Substring(directoryName.TrimEnd('\\').Length+1) inside the loop.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, that can be done with Directory.Move:

```
                try
                {
                    Directory.Move(source, destination);
                }
                catch { }
```

don't see any reason, why you shouldn't use this function. It's recursive and speed optimized

Comment: What if destination directory already exists? You should consider (before calling `Move`) to do a `Directory.Delete(destination, true)`, if that is successful, then call `Move`

Comment: This is the best answer here. There is no need to check if destination folder exists, source folder will be automatically deleted after Directory.Move is executed

Comment: This should not be used the folder you are moving to has contents in it, so should not be when you want to combine the contents of the target with the source files / subfolders

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Directory object to do this, but you might run into problems if you have the same file name in multiple sub directories (e.g. album1\1.mp3, album2\1.mp3) so you might need a little extra logic to tack something unique onto the names (e.g. album1-1.mp4).

```
    public void CopyDir( string sourceFolder, string destFolder )
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists( destFolder ))
            Directory.CreateDirectory( destFolder );

        // Get Files & Copy
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles( sourceFolder );
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileName( file );

            // ADD Unique File Name Check to Below!!!!
            string dest = Path.Combine( destFolder, name );
            File.Copy( file, dest );
        }

        // Get dirs recursively and copy files
        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories( sourceFolder );
        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileName( folder );
            string dest = Path.Combine( destFolder, name );
            CopyDir( folder, dest );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 public void MoveDirectory(string[] source, string target)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<Folders>();
        stack.Push(new Folders(source[0], target));
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var folders = stack.Pop();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folders.Target);
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folders.Source, "*.*"))
            {
                string targetFile = Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(file));
                if (File.Exists(targetFile)) File.Delete(targetFile); File.Move(file, targetFile);
            }
            foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folders.Source))
            {
                stack.Push(new Folders(folder, Path.Combine(folders.Target, Path.GetFileName(folder))));
            }
        }
        Directory.Delete(source[0], true);
    } 
}


public class Folders { 
    public string Source { 
        get; private set; 
    } 
    public string Target { 
        get; private set; 
    } 
    public Folders(string source, string target) { 
        Source = source; 
        Target = target; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get you rolling. You'll have to add error checking and what not (What if there is a subdirectory of source named "Consolidated"? What if Consolidated already exists? Etc.) This is from memory, so pardon any syntax errors, etc.

```
string source = @"C:\Music";
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(source);
string consolidated = Path.Combine(source, "Consolidated")
Directory.CreateDirectory(consolidated);
foreach(var directory in directories) {
    Directory.Move(directory, consolidated);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    private static void MoveFiles(string sourceDir, string targetDir)
    {
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir).Select(f => new FileInfo(f));
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            File.Move(file.FullName, Path.Combine(targetDir, file.Name));
        }
    }
```

Comment: To be more error proof, **Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir)** and **File.Move(file.FullName, destinationFileName)** to be checked if directory exists. Throws an DirectoryNotFoundException otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

We already had variant for copying directory structure, so this is just modified version of it for moving:

```cs
public static void MoveInner(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool moveSubDirs)
{
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
    var dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

    // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception
    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    // If the destination directory does not exist, create it
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);


    // Get the file contents of the directory to copy
    var files = dir.GetFiles();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        // Create the path to the new copy of the file
        var temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);

        // Move the file.
        file.MoveTo(temppath);
    }

    // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories
    if (!moveSubDirs)
        return;

    foreach (var subdir in dirs)
    {
        // Create the subdirectory
        var temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

        // Move the subdirectories
        MoveInner(subdir.FullName, temppath, moveSubDirs: true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String directoryName = @"D:\NewAll\";
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
        if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

        List<String> AllFiles= Directory
                           .GetFiles(@"D:\SourceDirectory\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        foreach (string file in AllFiles)
        {
            FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);

            // to remove name collisions
            if (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
            {
                mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                string s = mFile.Name.Substring(0, mFile.Name.LastIndexOf('.'));

                int a = 0;
                while (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + s + a.ToString() + mFile.Extension).Exists)
                {
                    a++;
                }
                mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + s + a.ToString() + mFile.Extension);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

ToCopyIt is important to mention that you can't use the ".move()" method across volumes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-6.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.move?view=net-6.0

Move files:

```
string DirFrom = @"C:\MyWork";
string DirTo = @"E:\Archive";

DirectoryInfo DirInfoFrom = new DirectoryInfo(DirFrom);
DirectoryInfo DirInfoTo = new DirectoryInfo(DirTo);

if (!DirInfoTo.Exists)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(DirTo);
}

foreach (FileInfo FileToCopy in DirInfoFrom.GetFiles())
{
    FileToCopy.CopyTo(DirTo + FileToCopy.Name);
    File.Delete(FileToCopy.FullName);
}
```

Tested 1/31/22 .NET4.8 VS2019

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the folders (nested or not) including their files to another folder (destination) with one function call (static void CopyDirectory(string sourceDir, string destinationDir, bool recursive)):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably find this helpful to dedup your mp3's that have a different file name but same title.

[source from David @ msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d2e9e48-8a02-419f-91e1-c61faf28bcf7/get-audio-files-info-ie-artist-name-title-album-art?forum=csharpgeneral)!

```
byte[] b = new byte[128];
string sTitle;
string sSinger;
string sAlbum;
string sYear;
string sComm;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
fs.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
fs.Read(b, 0, 128);
bool isSet = false;
String sFlag = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 0, 3);
if (sFlag.CompareTo("TAG") == 0)
{
System.Console.WriteLine("Tag   is   setted! ");
isSet = true;
}
if (isSet)
{
//get   title   of   song; 
sTitle = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 3, 30);
System.Console.WriteLine("Title: " + sTitle);
//get   singer; 
sSinger = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 33, 30);
System.Console.WriteLine("Singer: " + sSinger);
//get   album; 
sAlbum = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 63, 30);
System.Console.WriteLine("Album: " + sAlbum);
//get   Year   of   publish; 
sYear = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 93, 4);
System.Console.WriteLine("Year: " + sYear);
//get   Comment; 
sComm = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 97, 30);
System.Console.WriteLine("Comment: " + sComm);
}
System.Console.WriteLine("Any   key   to   exit! ");
System.Console.Read();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This post is not an answer to the question, which b.t.w. has already been answered quite well. Please do not use answers to elaborate on the original question.

Answer (score -2):

You loop through them and then simply run [Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx), the Directory class have functionality for listing contents too iirc.

Answer (score -2):

MSDN : [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx)

```
private void DirectoryCopy(
            string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception.
            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                    "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                    + sourceDirName);
            }

            // If the destination directory does not exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }


            // Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);

                // Copy the file.
                file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
            }

            // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories.
            if (copySubDirs)
            {

                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    // Create the subdirectory.
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

                    // Copy the subdirectories.
                    DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This looks like it was taken directly from MSDN.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx  Please reference the source when you take code from others.

Comment: @denver - done. i generally put references e.g http://stackoverflow.com/a/15880280/1060656

Answer (score -2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        movedirfiles(@"E:\f1", @"E:\f2");
    }
    static void movedirfiles(string sourdir,string destdir)
    {
        string[] dirlist = Directory.GetDirectories(sourdir);

        moveallfiles(sourdir, destdir);
        if (dirlist!=null && dirlist.Count()>0)
        {
            foreach(string dir in dirlist)
            {
                string dirName = destdir+"\\"+ new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
                moveallfiles(dir,dirName);
            }
        }

    }
    static void moveallfiles(string sourdir,string destdir)
    {
        string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(sourdir);
        if (filelist != null && filelist.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in filelist)
            {
                File.Copy(file, string.Concat(destdir, "\\"+Path.GetFileName(file)));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You copying files instead of moving