# Paths from a directory tree array

Tags: c#, directory

I am using `Directory.GetFiles` to find files that will be copied. I need to find the paths of the files so I can use copy, but I have no idea how to find the path.
It iterates through the files fine, but I can't copy or move them because I need the file's source path.

This is what I have:

```cpp
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

System.Console.WriteLine("Files Found");

// Display all the files.
foreach (string file in files)
{
  string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
  string thenameofdoom = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
  string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);

  bool b = false;
  string newlocation = (@"\\TEST12CVG\Public\Posts\Temporaryjunk\");

  if (extension == ".pst" || 
    extension == ".tec" || 
    extension == ".pas" || 
    extension == ".snc" || 
    extension == ".cst")
  {
    b = true;
  }

  if (thenameofdoom == "Plasma" || 
    thenameofdoom == "Oxygas" || 
    thenameofdoom == "plasma" || 
    thenameofdoom == "oxygas" || 
    thenameofdoom == "Oxyfuel" || 
    thenameofdoom == "oxyfuel")
  {
    b = false;
  }

  if (b == true)
  {
    File.Copy(file, newlocation + thenameofdoom);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Success: " + filename);
    b = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It has more, but I put what was necessary up. I need it for my job that I work at, and I need is sooner rather than later.

Comment: Do you mean `Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)`?

Comment: I need the entire path, not just the folder the file is in.

Comment: I have only ever used C# for 2 days now, yesterday was the first time I ever used it. But I think I am doing pretty good considering that fact.

Comment: Path.GetFullPath Method ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx

Comment: Or more info:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911595/move-all-files-in-subfolders-to-another-folder-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path.GetFullPath` works, but also consider using `FileInfo` as it comes with many file helper methods.

I would use a method similar to this (could use a lot more error handling (try catches...) but it's a good start

**EDIT** I noticed that you are filtering out the extensions, but requiring them, update to code allows for that

```
class BackupOptions
{
  public IEnumerable<string> ExtensionsToAllow { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<string> ExtensionsToIgnore { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<string> NamesToIgnore { get; set; }
  public bool CaseInsensitive { get; set; }

  public BackupOptions()
  {
    ExtensionsToAllow = new string[] { };
    ExtensionsToIgnore = new string[] { };
    NamesToIgnore = new string[] { };
  }
}

static void Backup(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, BackupOptions options = null)
{

  if (options == null)
    optionns = new BackupOptions();

  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
  StringComparison comp = options.CaseInsensitive ? StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase : StringComparison.CurrentCulture;

  foreach (var file in files)
  {
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);

    if (options.ExtensionsToAllow.Count() > 0 &&
      !options.ExtensionsToAllow.Any(allow => info.Extension.Equals(allow, comp)))
      continue;

    if (options.ExtensionsToIgnore.Any(ignore => info.Extension.Equals(ignore, comp)))
        continue;

    if (options.NamesToIgnore.Any(ignore => info.Name.Equals(ignore, comp)))
      continue;

    try
    {
      File.Copy(info.FullName, destinationPath + "\\" + info.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // report/handle error
    }
  }
}
```

With a call like:

```
var options = new BackupOptions
{
  ExtensionsToAllow = new string[] { ".pst", ".tec", ".pas", ".snc", ".cst" },
  NamesToIgnore = new string[] { "Plasma", "Oxygas", "Oxyfuel" },
  CaseInsensitive = true
};

Backup("D:\\temp", "D:\\backup", options);
```

Comment: The files are on a server, and they will be put on another server, I think what eric told me works (It didn't exception for any reason other than permissions), it is having a permissions issue I will have to get sorted out. there isn't anything than really needs error handling.

Comment: @shred1894 Path.GetDirectoryName(file) is no better than the code I provided. Working with UNC paths, i.e. `\\servername\...` doesn't matter to the code, this code will work just as well. In any workable solution you choose, your process will need appropriate read and write permissions, even regardless of local or remote files.

Comment: @shred1894 note that I am using `FileInfo` as it has many great helper methods to get paths and names and extensions very easily.

Comment: I wasn't talking about getdirectoryfilename, I was talking about getfullpath, I set up some tests for it, and it worked how I needed it to, so thanks for all the help.

Comment: now I need to make it create directories and put the copied files in them, but besides that, it works.

Comment: here is what I need now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352190/more-of-paths-and-such