# More of paths and such

Tags: c#, arrays, file, tree, directory

I am making a script that finds what the 2nd folder in the path is, how would I do this?

dirA
dirB/C ---- I need dirB
indirB - dirD/E
indirE - The file

I need to find the name of the folder in the 2nd level that paths to the file (I marked it with stars).

how would I go about finding this

Comment: It is for my file copy/sorter thing.

Comment: I have no idea what you just typed up.

Comment: question is more complicated than it should be. Is your question I have path `c:\a\b\c` how do I get `b`?

Comment: Drop the confusing illustration - write up several paths and explain, for each what you need returned. Of course, first explain why you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I tried to make a diagram of a tree. I am stuck because I am new to C#, and I do not know all of the methods and stuff.

Comment: You shouldn't have posted it if you didn't succeed.

Comment: just off the top of my head, why not load each folder recursively into a treeview and return every tree item of 2nd level? Obviously there's an easier way but I can't think of it...

Comment: Do you know a string that represents the path to the file, or are you running a search?

Comment: there are about 400 folders in the 2nd level

Comment: I would suggest to rewrite your sample to use more easy to read names like folder A and folder B, C is inside A so just write A/C. Why such an abstract sample if the plan is that simple? Or has "this" a special meaning in this (not your this here) context?

Comment: and the files have been found recursively already, but I need the 2nd level of the paths to figure out what directories to make to put the files in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this extension:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static String PathLevel(this String path, int level)
    {
        if (path == null) throw new ArgumentException("Path must not be null", "path");
        if (level < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Level must be >= 0", "level");

        var levels = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
        return levels.Length > level ? levels[level] : null;
    }
}
```

testing:

```
var path = @"C:\Temp\Level2\Level3\Level4\File.txt";
var secondLevel = path.PathLevel(2); // => "Level2"
```

It splits the path by [`DirectorySeparatorChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx) to a `String[]`. 
You wanted the second level(the third element), this returns "Level2". Note that the first element is `C:`.

Comment: If `level.Length` is `2`, this code would raise an out of bound exception.

Comment: I have only been using C# for 3 days now, never used it before.

Comment: I do not need the first level though, just the second

Comment: @shred1894 I suggest you to read a book first, try something and then if you stuck ask here.

Comment: @RenWell I am doing this for my job, I do not have time to read a book, and the last time I had tried to learn a  scripting language from a book, I didn't learn a thing.

Comment: no, I am asking a forum to assist me in solving a problem, I could have just posted the entire thing and said: "This doesn't work, can you fix it"